# Deploy existing project on a new dev account

Tags: mavensmate, sublime

I cloned an existing project on my local and I would like to deploy the changes I'm doing into my dev account, this is a fresh new account.

I'm using sublime-text with mavensmate and I created the connection with my account and token but I cannot compile or deploy the app.

Moreover when I try to compile I get this error :

```
Result: [DEPLOYMENT FAILED]: SendOpportunityController.cls: sObject type 'Customer_Method__c' is not supported. If you are attempting to use a custom object, be sure to append the '__c' after the entity name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names. (Line: 208, Column: 29)
```

and many like this ...

I also get `Dependent class is invalid and needs recompilation` but I think it's related to the previous error.

is there a way to deploy this code from sublimetext to a new developer org in one hit?

Comment: Does your "clone" include a Customer_Method__c.object file? Any component referenced in the components your deploy must either be included in the deployment (the best approach) or be already present in the target org.

Comment: No I don't have any of these files, should it be under src/classes ?

Comment: It would be under src/objects.

Answer (score 1):

Moving an entire project, from scratch, is seldom pretty, especially if you're trying to do so by hand. It's fraught with perils. I usually recommend that you start by building a *package*, which is more or less fully contained, as it is designed to be a system where you can move an element and all related elements to a different org with little-to-no pre-configuration, such as how ISVs create installable apps.

Go to Setup > Create > Packages, and add just the elements you think you need. For example, add your page that uses this controller. It will automatically add the class, fields, and objects you need to deploy with the page automatically. Once you're satisfied, you can use MavensMate or Force.com IDE to pull down that entire package as one unit, then you can deploy it to the new destination just as easily.

Comment: 3 pages + meta and 25 classes + their meta + their tests, its lot of pages to manually create, is their another way to bulk import them ?

Comment: It's all point and click, creating packages in the UI. Shouldn't take more than a couple of minutes, tops. Like I said, it automatically resolves dependencies, so you shouldn't need to select all 40+ items.